# multiple instances of odometer.js

Tags: jquery

I am using [odometer.js](http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/)

My code is as follows:

```
<h3 class="odometer-github-stars">
   <span class="odometer-label">Upload Speed: <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up"></i></span>
   <div class="odometer odometer-theme-minimal">0</div>
</h3>
```

Script to initiate:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.odometer').html('4564');
    }, 
      1000
    );
```

The issue I am having is I wish to add a second and third instance of a odometer, I thought it may be a case of adding another class of say:

```
<div class="odometer_number_two odometer-theme-minimal">0</div>
```

etc. Then adding additional functions, like:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.odometer_number_two').html('1234');
    }, 
      1000
    );
```

But really not getting anywhere.

Anyone, got any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`odometer` is a requited class for the default usage, so you will have to use it in both items, you just need to target the element another way..

Either use another class or an id to target it..

```
<div class="odometer odometer_number_one odometer-theme-minimal">0</div>
<div class="odometer odometer_number_two odometer-theme-minimal">0</div>
```

and

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.odometer_number_one').html('4564');
    $('.odometer_number_two').html('1234');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: arggh perfect, your a star. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to support multiple odometer instances is to use a different id for each odometer.

Example:

```
<div id="odometer1" class="odometer odometer-theme-minimal">0</div>
<div id="odometer2" class="odometer odometer-theme-minimal">0</div>
```

Change the values of the particular odometers with:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#odometer1').html('1234');
    $('#odometer2').html('2345');
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of Multiple Dynamic Odometers(Available inside table). Implemented in MVC(c#)

defined **`<td>`** here

```
<td class="text-center">                                                                                                                   
    <div id="@string.Concat("divOffsetCumulativeHours-",item.Asset_ID)" class="odometer odometer1">@item.OffsetCumulativeWorkingHours</div>                                    
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnOffsetCumulativeHour" name="hdnOffsetCumulativeHour" value="@item.OffsetCumulativeWorkingHours" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnOdometerDivIdValue" name="hdnOdometerDivIdValue" value="@string.Concat("divOffsetCumulativeHours-",item.ID)" />
    </div>                       
</td>
```

And the script

```
function InitializeOdometers()
    {
        var todaygridtable = $('#divtodaysview').find('table');
        //If there is a table exists inside the div - then find the OffsetCumulativeHour and OdometerDivIdValue hiddencontrol inside each row
        if (todaygridtable) {
            //Loop through the whole row wise "Today's View table"
            var rows = $("#tblTodaysView").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var tr = $(rows[i]);
                //Get the CumulativeHour Value in each row
                var offsetCumulativeHour = $(tr).find($('input[name="hdnOffsetCumulativeHour"]')).val();
                //Find the div id for the odometer - saved in another hidden control
                var odometerDivIdHidden = $(tr).find($('input[name="hdnOdometerDivIdValue"]')).val();
                if (offsetCumulativeHour) {
                    //Find the odometer div
                    var odometerDiv = $(tr).find($('#' + odometerDivIdHidden));
                    //Find the default value assigned to odometer div
                    var defaultVal = parseFloat($(odometerDiv).text().trim()).toFixed(2);
                    //Find the Correct(New) Value to be assign to odometer div
                    var newVal = parseFloat(offsetCumulativeHour).toFixed(2);
                    if (typeof defaultVal === 'undefined' || defaultVal == null) {
                        defaultVal = 0.00;
                    }
                    //Generate Odometer Object with the Odometer div
                    var $container = $(odometerDiv);
                    if ($container && $container.get(0))
                    {
                        var odometer = new Odometer({
                            el: $container.get(0),
                            value: defaultVal,
                            format: '(ddd).dd',
                            theme: 'train-station'
                        });
                        odometer.render();
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            debugger;
                            //Assign new value to Odometer div
                            //$container.text(newVal); // value to reach
                            odometer.update(newVal);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```